# Keeping rows in Pandas where the same ID appears more than n times and convert to list per ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like below:

```
     VID  value
1     1    xx
2     2    xx1
3     2    xx2
4     2    xx3
5     2    xx4
6     3    xx
7     3    xx
8     3    xx
9     4    zz1
10    4    zz2
11    4    zz3
12    4    zz4
13    4    zz5
```

I want to keep only the rows whose VID exists in more than n=3 cases. In the above example, I'd keep only rows 2-5 and 9-13 (since only the VIDs 2 and 4 appear more than 3 times). The 'value' field is irrelevant.

After keeping the needed rows, I'd like to convert my data as a list of lists while appending an 'end' value at the end of each one:

```
[[xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4, 'end'], [zz1, zz2, zz3, zz4, zz5, 'end']]
```

Is it possible to get the above without a `for` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group by `VID` column and then take count of each group. Then after that use it for indexing your original df, so as to only take rows that have greater than 3 count. Example -

```
countdf = df.groupby('VID').count()
result = df.loc[df['VID'].isin(countdf[countdf['value'] > 3].index)]
```

Demo -

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
    VID value
1     1    xx
2     2   xx1
3     2   xx2
4     2   xx3
5     2   xx4
6     3    xx
7     3    xx
8     3    xx
9     4   zz1
10    4   zz2
11    4   zz3
12    4   zz4
13    4   zz5

In [51]: df.groupby('VID').count()
Out[51]:
     value
VID
1        1
2        4
3        3
4        5

In [52]: countdf = df.groupby('VID').count()

In [53]: df.loc[df['VID'].isin(countdf[countdf['value'] > 3].index)]
Out[53]:
    VID value
2     2   xx1
3     2   xx2
4     2   xx3
5     2   xx4
9     4   zz1
10    4   zz2
11    4   zz3
12    4   zz4
13    4   zz5
```

---

Then after this, you can again group based on `VID` and then convert the groups into `list` and then again to list , Example -

```
resultlist = result.groupby('VID')['value'].apply(list).tolist()
```

Demo -

```
In [54]: result = df.loc[df['VID'].isin(countdf[countdf['value'] > 3].index)]

In [55]: result.groupby('VID')['value'].apply(list).tolist()
Out[55]: [['xx1', 'xx2', 'xx3', 'xx4'], ['zz1', 'zz2', 'zz3', 'zz4', 'zz5']]
```

---

Please note, above would not get you the `'end'` value in the list, I am guessing that is not necessary, but if you really want that, you can manually add it after getting the list. Example -

```
resultlist = [elem + ['end'] for elem in resultlist]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! The speed-up compared to my 'for loop' version is amazing. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In case anyone else is interested in recreating and tweaking this example, here is code that can be used to create the sample DataFrame:
`df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'VID': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
     'value': ['xx', 'xx1', 'xx2', 'xx3', 'xx4', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'zz1', 'zz2', 'zz3', 'zz4', 'zz5']})`